# Handling failure scenarios of AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

If my lambda function fails, is there any way in AWS to invoke the same function after 3-4 hours.

If yes what would be the flow to do so?

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: I want to invoke the lambda function again if it fails but not immediately, I want to invoke it after 3-4 hours of time. @Marcin

Comment: So invoke it. What is the issue with invoking it again, the same way you invoked it the first time?

Comment: I want it to get invoked automatically after 3-4 hours @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the failure. Clients such as the AWS CLI and the AWS SDK retry on client timeouts, throttling errors (429), and other errors that aren't caused by a bad request. Read more about auto retries in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html).

If you want a custom retry logic, Dead Letter Queue can be an option. See more details in here https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/compute/robust-serverless-application-design-with-aws-lambda-dlq/

Or you can use CloudWatch event to trigger on lambda failure.

[image]
Here is a  good article explains that approach.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/get-notified-specific-lambda-function-error-patterns-using-cloudwatch/